# Exponential calculation in Python

Tags: python, optimization, largenumber, exponentiation

While experimenting with [Euler 99](https://projecteuler.net/problem=99), I noticed that these operations take different time:

```
>>> 632382**518061  # never finishes..

>>> 632382**518061 > 519432**525806  # finishes in few seconds
True
```

I wonder what's the reason for this?

Comment: As a side issue, when the Python compiler sees `632382**518061`, it thinks, "hey, simple operation on two smallish integer literals, I'll do that at compile-time and constant-fold it". So, it takes something like 3 seconds to compile that line of code, but only 20 nanoseconds to run it (and then 200 seconds to format the string to print…). On the interactive interpreter that doesn't matter (unless you try to benchmark with `timeit`), but put it in a module and `import` that module, and the first time will take 3 seconds, but if you do it again (even after quitting and relaunching) it won't.

Comment: By the way, even without reading problem 99, I suspect the point of it is to give you numbers that are too big to actually calculate, so you have to know and/or look up and learn some trick like modular exponentiation or dividing out factors from each side and only calculating when there are no common factors or estimating and then testing that the error ranges.

Comment: Memory and time are compromised when trying to display a number with many digits as seen in the first example. In the second, there is no attempt to actually display, just a simple comparison which does not consume as much time as printing to the standard output.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The thing is python tries to print the first result. But this number has a zillion digits and python doesn't flush the output until a newline is encountered, which is after sending all the digits to standard output. As @abarnert mentioned, what is many times worse, is converting the number to string for printing it. This needs considerable memory allocation and processing power. On the other side, the second expression just needs to print a `True`. You can check it if you assign to the first expression:

```
 >>> a = 632382**518061
```

This way the output of the number is suppressed.

Comment: I think it's more formatting the giant string and printing it to output. On my machine, it takes 1.68s to compile the multiplication, 24.6ns to eval the resulting compiled literal, 28s to `str` it, and only 2s to `write` it. On Windows it might take a lot more time to write, or in IDLE, but on a decent stdout it shouldn't be the main bottleneck.

Comment: That 28s is for Python 2.7, and 3.4 is pretty close, but in 3.2, the `str` part takes at least 6 minutes; I'm going to ^C it now…

Comment: @abarnert It makes sense, can I add it in my answer?